# What is a better way to decode/encode binary little endian data in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

What is a best approach to get rid of a boilerplate code that serializes/deserializes binary data in Haskell, taking endianness into account? I.e., given this struct:

```
data Foobar = Foobar { foo :: Word16, bar :: Word32 }
```

And derived `Data.Binary.Binary` type class instance:

```
instance Binary Foobar where
  get = do
    foo <- get
    bar <- get
    return $ Foobar foo bar
```

`decode stream :: Foobar` treats the data as big endian.

Obvious way is to use `getWord16le`/`getWord32le` functions, but it involves lots of manual work (which could be automatically and nicely done by Template Haskell coupled with [derive](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/derive)).

Perhaps, parametrized types are the solution?

Comment: Aren't the pre-declared instances for Binary always big endian? Working with both big and little endian looks like a recipe for inscrutable errors. If you want to write and parse data in a pre-existing little endian binary format, I'd recommend you avoid making instances of Binary and write a parser and serializer directly without type classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about defining little-endian newtypes for words?

```
newtype LWord16 = LWord16 { unLWord16 :: Word16 }
newtype LWord32 = LWord32 { unLWord32 :: Word32 }
instance Binary LWord16 where get = LWord16 <$> getWord16le
instance Binary LWord32 where get = LWord32 <$> getWord32le
```

Then deriving Binary for the definition

```
data Foobar = Foobar { foo :: LWord16, bar :: LWord32 }
```

should do the right thing.

Comment: It worked - thanks!
Also, `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` is very helpful in this case.

Comment: For posterity: these days, one would probably write `instance Binary LWord16 where get = coerce getWord16le; put = coerce putWord16le` to avoid the (probably very tiny) overhead of calling `fmap`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a typeclass for different Word types, such as:

```
class BinaryEndian a where
   getEndian :: Get a
   putEndian :: a -> Put

instance BinaryEndian Word16 where
   getEndian = getWord16le
   putEndian = putWord16le
```

etc.

That would make TH code perhaps a little easier to write.